# Attribute addition and deletion based on array change

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm maintaining the array that stores the order of the checkboxes selected.
I've to add the attribute 'data-count' to the first element of the array as 1, 2nd element as 2, and so on...
Once the element is removed from the array, I need to remove the attribute 'data-count' that has already been assigned to it.

I need to find a way to assign 'data-count' to elements based on it's position on the array and remove the attribute when element is removed from the checkbox...?

Here is jsfiddle so far what i've: https://jsfiddle.net/skt6v1o9/15/

```
<ul class="dropdown-content checkboxes">
    <li class="ch1">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" />Billy</label>
    </li>
    <li class="ch2">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" />Jacob</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" />Bob</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" />Alexandren</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" />Erren</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" />Stewgart</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" />Jillian</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" />Other</label>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="result"></div>

var order = [];

$("[type=checkbox]").on('change', function() {
    var idx = order.indexOf(this);
    
    if (idx !== -1) {
        order.splice(idx, 1);
    }

    if (this.checked) {
        order.push(this);
    }
    
    var map = $.map(order, function(elem) {
        return $(elem).closest('li');
    });
    console.log(map);
   $(map[0]).attr('data-count', 1);
   $(map[1]).attr('data-count', 2);
   $(map[2]).attr('data-count', 3);
});
```

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/qLpwj6ok/

Comment: thank you for the quick response! Adding 'data-count' works but I also need to remove the data-count attribute when the element is removed from the array(unchecked). Eg., When Billy and Jacob is checked. map has [Billy, Jacob]. data-count of Billy is 0, Jacob is 1. When Billy is unchecked, map array has [Jacob], data-count which is already assigned to Billy should be removed now as it is not in the array. Thanks!

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Billy and Jacob is checked then <li data-count="0">Billy</li> <li data-count="1">Jacob</li>. When Billy is unchecked it should be <li>Billy</li> <li data-count="0">Jacob</li>. Currently it's like: <li data-count="0">Billy</li> <li data-count="0">Jacob</li> We need to remove data-count attribute from the element when unchecked

Comment: I think I can achieve this by removing 'data-count' to all checkboxes before assigning using each(map). Not sure if it's ideal way to do it